# Can't map Model values to formcontrols

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When i am trying to map the response from server to formcontrols in angular 6 using a model class during editing the values, the form control waits for an event  to set the value. Even if there is response in the model, why I can't set the form control value using model? how can i solve this problem

```
this.patientRegistrationService.getdata(data).subscribe(result=>
       {
        this.pmaster=result.pmaster;
        //pmaster is a model class
       }
```

Comment: `its not mapping` what do you mean?

Comment: Cant map the value from  response to form control during editing

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] and put a bit more effort into properly explaining your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it help:

If you have a formgroup named myForm & a form control named country:

```
this.patientRegistrationService.getdata(data).subscribe(result=>
{ 
        this.myForm.get('country').setValue(result.curCountry);
}
```